How to pass parameters to task from file
I create a file with a content and I need to pass this to my task paramaters:
The original tasks is like this:
- name: Configure Web filter profiles.
  fortinet.fortios.fortios_webfilter_profile:
    vdom: "{{ vdom }}"
    state: "present"
    access_token: "x4jcqmpwhrgdjw0p4qnHcw35m5GH63"
    webfilter_profile:
      feature_set: flow
      name: "{{ wf_name }}"
      ftgd_wf:
        options: "error-allow"
        filters:
            -
              action: "block"
              category: "41"
              id: "41"
              log: "enable"
              warn_duration: "5m"
              warning_duration_type: "timeout"
              warning_prompt: "per-category"
        max_quota_timeout: "300"
        rate_crl_urls: "enable"
        rate_css_urls: "enable"
        rate_javascript_urls: "enable"

When I use this playbook works fine but I need to create multiple lines for multiples IDs, something like this:
- name: Configure Web filter profiles.
  fortinet.fortios.fortios_webfilter_profile:
    vdom: "{{ vdom }}"
    state: "present"
    access_token: "x4jcqmpwhrgdjw0p4qnHcw35m5GH63"
    webfilter_profile:
      feature_set: flow
      name: "{{ wf_name }}"
      ftgd_wf:
        options: "error-allow"
        filters:
            -
              action: "block"
              category: "41"
              id: "41"
              log: "enable"
              warn_duration: "5m"
              warning_duration_type: "timeout"
              warning_prompt: "per-category"
            -
              action: "block"
              category: "42"
              id: "42"
              log: "enable"
              warn_duration: "5m"
              warning_duration_type: "timeout"
              warning_prompt: "per-category"
            -
              action: "block"
              category: "42"
              id: "42"
              log: "enable"
              warn_duration: "5m"
              warning_duration_type: "timeout"
              warning_prompt: "per-category"
            (--- etc ids)
        max_quota_timeout: "300"
        rate_crl_urls: "enable"
        rate_css_urls: "enable"
        rate_javascript_urls: "enable"

So I create a file using lineinfile modules to add lines as Id numbers exists:
- name: Create file
  file:
    path: "/tmp/wf_content.txt"
    state: touch
    mode: '0775'

- name: Add lines in file
  lineinfile:
    path: "/tmp/wf_content.txt"
    line: |
          '-
            action: "block"
            category: "{{ item }}"
            id: "{{ item }}"
            log: "enable"
            warn_duration: "5m"
            warning_duration_type: "timeout"
            warning_prompt: "per-category"'
  loop: "{{ id_number }}"

- name: remove blank lines in file
  shell: "sed -e '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' wf_content.txt > wf_content2.txt"
  args:
    chdir: "/tmp/"

But when I replace the content of task from my file I got "dictionary requested, could not parse JSON or key=value"
My full playbooks is the next:
- name: Create file with context to fortinet
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    vars_fortinet.yml

  tasks: 

    - name: Create file
      file:
      path: "/tmp/wf_content.txt"
      state: touch
      mode: '0775'

    - name: Add lines in file
      lineinfile:
        path: "/tmp/wf_content.txt"
        line: |
            '-
              action: "block"
              category: "{{ item }}"
              id: "{{ item }}"
              log: "enable"
              warn_duration: "5m"
              warning_duration_type: "timeout"
              warning_prompt: "per-category"'
      loop: "{{ id_number }}"

    - name: remove blank lines in file
      shell: "sed -e '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' wf_content.txt > wf_content2.txt"
      args:
        chdir: "/tmp/"

- name: Test connection to fortinet
  hosts: fortinet
  connection: httpapi
  become: false
  vars:
  ansible_httpapi_use_ssl: yes
  ansible_httpapi_validate_certs: false
  ansible_network_os: fortinet.fortios.fortios
  vdom: "VDOM_BOT"
  wf_name: wf_10_0_0_3
# Esto debe pasarlo el chatbot -- Convertir la IP de punto a subguión
  vars_files:
    vars_fortinet.yml  

  tasks:

  - name: Get values from file
    shell: "cat /tmp/wf_content2.txt"
    register: output

  - name: Configure Web filter profiles.
    fortinet.fortios.fortios_webfilter_profile:
      vdom: "{{ vdom }}"
      state: "present"
      access_token: "x4jcqmpwhrgdjw0p4qnHcw35m5GH63"
      webfilter_profile:
        feature_set: flow
        name: "{{ wf_name }}"
        ftgd_wf:
          options: "error-allow"
          filters:
            "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
          max_quota_timeout: "300"
          rate_crl_urls: "enable"
          rate_css_urls: "enable"
          rate_javascript_urls: "enable"

I hope you can help with this and sorry for my bad English.

Given the list ids
ids: [41, 42, 43]

Create a template instead of a text file. For example,
shell> cat wf_content.j2
{% filter from_yaml %}
{% for id in ids %}
- action: block
  category: {{ id }}
  id: {{ id }}
  log: enable
  warn_duration: 5m
  warning_duration_type: timeout
  warning_prompt: per-category
{% endfor %}
{% endfilter %}

Create the list filters
  filters: "{{ lookup('template', 'wf_content.j2') }}"

gives
  filters:
  - action: block
    category: 41
    id: 41
    log: enable
    warn_duration: 5m
    warning_duration_type: timeout
    warning_prompt: per-category
  - action: block
    category: 42
    id: 42
    log: enable
    warn_duration: 5m
    warning_duration_type: timeout
    warning_prompt: per-category
  - action: block
    category: 43
    id: 43
    log: enable
    warn_duration: 5m
    warning_duration_type: timeout
    warning_prompt: per-category

Use it in the module. Put the declaration, for example, into the task's vars
- name: Configure Web filter profiles.
  fortinet.fortios.fortios_webfilter_profile:
    vdom: "{{ vdom }}"
    state: present
    access_token: "x4jcqmpwhrgdjw0p4qnHcw35m5GH63"
    webfilter_profile:
      feature_set: flow
      name: "{{ wf_name }}"
      ftgd_wf:
        options: error-allow
        filters: "{{ filters }}"
  ...
  vars:
    filters: "{{ lookup('template', 'wf_content.j2') }}"


It works. Thanks for help.
